# Android new project no code, apk is 4 mb

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

I'm creating a simple pro package to unlock features in my free app.

My free app will check if the pro package is installed and unlock pro features if its installed. I created a new project, with no activity. When I pushed it the app to my device it says it's 4 mb in size. Why is it so big when theres no code? Looking at other apps with pro unlockers, they seem very small like 100-200 kb.

build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.dsmartapps.root.kerneltoolkitunlocker"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
}
```

Solution:
simply removed compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0' and its now 48.00kb.

Comment: What is a `simple pro package`? Did you just create this project? Post your `build.gradle`s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably has to do with the your Gradle build file. It's probably using the support library, if you have no use of it you can remove it.

EDIT:

Even so, as Jared said a single support library shouldn't make your apk size that big. You should check your dependencies and assets to see what makes up for that size.

Here's a simple Gradle file for a new project:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.edd.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
   }
   buildTypes {
       release {
           minifyEnabled false
           proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),'proguard-rules.pro'
       }
   }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
}
```

Size with `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'`: around 900kb.

Size without it: around 22kb.

Comment: That was it. Thanks! ill accept the answer in 4 min when I'm allowed

Comment: What? How is this an answer? A single support library will not make your application be 4mb.

Comment: It does mate. The library is quite big and has lots of assets, even more so if he created the project with the latest SDK.

Comment: Actually, you are right. It shouldn't be THAT big. There must've been other libraries imported too in that build file.

Comment: it was just the support library. the apk was 4.6 mb in size, I removed the line in build.gradle and now its 48 kb.

Comment: Can you post your gradle file in your question though? I'm curious.

Comment: added to question. I agree it seemed strange, as my main app is 6-7mb which contains several thousand lines of code and several other libraries including the support lib.