# Android apk size less than 20kb

Tags: android, apk, android-build

Need to build an android apk less than 20kb, and rest of the contents in the app should download dynamically, does anyone have idea about that.
If i create a simple android app and build it without any source code, it results in 3 MB atleast. 
So, so pls someone suggest me how can we create an apk in kb.

Comment: Why?  There's no magic to being less than 20k.  And the code to download the rest of the app alone is likely to come in at more than that.

Comment: Check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29785088/android-new-project-no-code-apk-is-4-mb

Answer (score 5):

I decided this would be a fun challenge, and was able to make a tiny app (no real functionality) that was 16kb. [You can find the source code here](https://github.com/bherbst/tiny_apk). It would have been even smaller with only ldpi assets.

Some caveats:

- Don't expect an app with any real functionality to come in this small. Keep in mind that 20kb is around 20,000 characters worth of data, which would be about the length of a very short story. 20kb really isn't realistic, and **you are going to end up taking up that extra space on your user's phone when you download the "rest of the app" later anyway.**
- My example has only mdpi assets. Things like launcher icons have to be bundled with your application, so either your icon will look awful on large devices, or you need to modify your requirements.

Some tips:

- Enable proguard. Both minification and obfuscation. The latter is a hyper-optimization, but when you are trying to go that small, every bit helps.
- Take out any libraries that aren't absolutely mission critical. You aren't going to make it with any of the support library.
- Support only the lowest resolution screens you can. ldpi assets will look bad on high density screens, but are exponentially smaller than mdpi, which is exponentially smaller than hdpi, etc. Resources are almost guaranteed to be the largest piece of the app.
- Read all of the [Shrink Your Code documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html). One great tip if you are using any libraries that provide resources is to [use `resConfigs`](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html#unused-alt-resources) to strip out any languages, densities, and native ABIs that you don't need.
- Android Studio 3.0 has an "analyze APK" feature that will break down what pieces of the APK are taking up the most space- use that to identify your targets for cutting down the size.

Comment: "_Don't expect an app with any real functionality to come in this small ... 20kb really isn't realistic_" Huh! Kids of today! The original Elite for the BBC Micro was only 22kB ([Telegraph article](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/games/11051122/Elite-the-game-that-changed-the-world.html)).

Comment: Comparing an app for an 8-bit computer with a 640×256, 8 color display to one for a 64-bit computer with a 1440x2880 16.77 million color display is a bit more than an apples - oranges comparison ;)

Comment: My tongue was somewhat in my cheek :-)